# SIGTERM signal arrives first to kuma and stops all active application connections immediately

Tags: apache-kafka, sigterm, graceful-shutdown, kuma

we have applications that work with Kafka (MSK), we noticed that once pod is starting to shutdown (during autoscaling or deployment) the app container loses all active connections and the SIGTERM signal causes Kuma to close all connections immediately which cause data loss due to unfinished sessions (which doesn’t get closed gracefully) on the app side and after that we receive connection errors to the kafka brokers,
is anyone have an idea how to make Kuma wait some time once it gets the SIGTERM signal to let the sessions close gracefully?
or maybe a way to let the app know before the kuma about the shutsown?
or any other idea ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue getting fixed in the coming 1.7 release: https://github.com/kumahq/kuma/pull/4229